# Anti debugging protection for React Native App

Tags: ios, react-native, security, penetration-testing, anti-debugging

How to implement Anti debugging protection for a React Native application (especially for iOS platform)?

I've not configured anything for anti debugging protection. But during penetration testing, issue has been reported to implement anti debugging protection for ios.

I found out ptrace implementation can be a one way for this. Does anyone have the exact solution on how to implement that successfully?

Also is there any other possible solutions available?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for can be found here.
You can implement "jscrambler". It has anti dubugging protection enabled.

https://jscrambler.com/blog/securing-react-native-applications